# Unable to post message to wall on facebook using facebook rules module

Tags: 7, social-network

I have following modules installed

1. [FBOauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/fboauth)
2. [Facebook Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_rules)

I have installed its dependencies like Rules and Oauth library.

The settings implemented on the facebook app

Dashboard

TEST
This app is public and available to all users
**App ID** : 
22321917809249
**App Secret** :
●●●●●●●●Show

In the below all the blurred value has been appropriately added.
[image]

Also in the status and review I have made following changes as shown in the image
[image]

In the facebook rules I have created a rule with following

**Events**
**User logged in using Facebook connect.  

User registered using Facebook connect, requires admin approval. 
 
User registered using Facebook connect.**

**Action**

**Post an update on user's facebook wall.
Parameter: Message: Hello Facebook world!, Link to post: m2w.redcom.in**

The api and secret key has been added on the facebook configuration settings page and I am able to retrieve the facebook details of the user on the  user details on the websites.
How can I post to the user's facebook wall using the above rules configuration? 
[image]

All while facebook is logged in and i try to use the fconnect feature, 
I get a message dialog box which has following text
"This does not let app post to the facebook"
How can I allow my app to post to the facebook. ??

Drupal Issue posted : https://www.drupal.org/node/2299375

Comment: your facebook configuration is not complete, on your second image, click on "start submission" and select items like "publish_actions" and submit it for review . the process is very annoying, hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with proper permission.
You need to have permission "publish_actions" to post on someone's behalf. If you do need more permissions then follow the below link to get all the permissions provided via Facebook Graph API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended